# InstallShied LE does not include dependencies from scan at build DLLs

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2013, installshield-le

I am trying to build an installer for a .NET Tablet application, it is a solution provided via Subversion (SVN) by another coworker (**which work very well**)

The problem is when I build the installer, **some DLLs are missing** at generation and at installation although they are in the "Primary output" bundle :

[image: picture showing that MahApps.Metro.dll is present and checked]

The installer build output shows :

```
15>Adding file 'log4net.dll' that is a dependency of component '***.Sortie_principale'
15>Adding file 'log4net.FX2.dll' that is a dependency of component '***.Sortie_principale'
15>Adding file 'Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll' that is a dependency of component '***.Sortie_principale'
15>Adding file 'MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel-WPF.dll' that is a dependency of component '***.Sortie_principale'
```

The program NEEDS those DLL, it crashes when I try to install it on my computer

Specs :

- Visual Studio 2013 Premium update 5
- InstallShield 2013 (then 2015) limited edition

What I have tried so far :

- Some DLLs were nuget reference, I removed them, but some other DLLs are also nuget packages and are included well. One DLL is a project of the solution, so nuget doesn't seem responsible for that
- Checkout the solution in another folder
- Those missing DLLs are not in GAC
- The folder `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework(64)?\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files`
- Built in release mode
- anyCPU build
- Specific versions : true
- Tried to remove/reinject the primary output
- Tried to remove/reinject the dependencies of the primary output using `dependencies from scan at build`
- Recreated an InstallShield project, ineffective

What can I check furthermore ? I can easily compare the project configuration of my coworker.

**UPDATE 1**

I've found something strange : apparently if Installshield doesn't find a dependance project (error -6248) and these DLL are part of this dependant project, it doesn't include them :

```
A -> (depends on) B -> C
If B is not found then C is not included, even if A -> C in the project dependencies.
```

Thank you for your help!